# C# UDF Worksheetfunction.SumIf not working

Tags: automation, sumifs

I tried to use SumIf function in C# .Net Automation Add-Ins but doesn't seem to work. To do a test, I made a simple function below. I got a **#Value!** error. I also tried hard coded all ranges in my function without luck.

```
public double subtotals(object criteria, object range, object sum_range)
{
    Exce.Application lApp = new Excel.Application();

    Excel.Range criterias = criteria as Excel.Range;
    Excel.Range ranges = range as Excel.Range;
    Excel.Range sum_ranges = sum_range as Excel.Range;

    return lApp.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ranges, criterias.Value2, sum_ranges);
}
```

Can someone enlighten me on this? Thanks a lot.